# Inheritance issue?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

So i am trying to create a stack class that inherits member functions from a linked list class. The linked list class has no actual implementation of its own; it's essentially an abstract virtual class. Both are template classes. When I try to access a member function using my derived stack class, I am receiving a "no member function declared in class 'Stack'" error. Below is my code. I'm not sure what the issue is. I have included the names of the .h files as well as the : public List sequence in the declaration of the stack class. Please help! If any more code is required for you to answer this question please let me know!! Thank you!

Code for declaration of List parent class

```
#ifndef LIST221_H
#define LIST221_H

#include "Node221.h"

template <typename T>
class List221 {

  public:
    List221();
    ~List221();

    virtual int size() const;
    virtual bool empty() const;
    virtual bool push(T obj); //will push in a new node
    virtual bool pop(); //will pop off the top node
    virtual bool clear();

  protected:


  private:
    Node<T>* front;
    Node<T>* rear;




};



#endif
```

Code for declaration of Stack class. 
***Includes List.h file***

```
#include "List221.h"
#include "Node221.h"


template <typename T>
class Stack221 : public List221 <T> {
  public:
    Stack221();
    ~Stack221();


    T top();


  private:
    Node<T>* topnode;

};
```

Example of Member function from List class that I am trying to access. 
Also includes List.h at top of page

```
template <typename T>
bool Stack221<T>::push(T obj) {
  Node<T>* o = new Node(obj);

  if (topnode == nullptr) {
    topnode = o;
  }
  else {
    o->next = topnode;
    topnode = o;
  }

  return true;
}
```

***Error being displayed***

```
 error: no ‘bool Stack221<T>::push(T)’ member function declared 
in class ‘Stack221<T>’
 bool Stack221<T>::push(T obj) {
                         ^
```

Comment: An [mcve] would help, we don’t know how the parent class has been declared.

Comment: I see nothing abot `bool Stack221<T>::clear()` in your example (check the displayed error in your code snippet)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have provided an implementation of `Stack221<T>::push`, but you have not declared that method in your class declaration.

Comment: The push function is meant to be inherited from the parent class. Shouldn't there be no need for a declaration in the derived class?

Comment: If you provide an implementation, you must provide a declaration.  If you are meaning to inherit the method from the parent class, why do you provide an implementation above?